# Как сделать так, чтобы первая строка в csv становилась индексами в pandas?

Tags: pandas, csv

Получаю данные из API - хочу, чтобы первая строка автоматически становилась индексами в pandas

[image: Кусок CSV]

Comment: советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060) и отредактировать вопрос соответственно

Comment: Подскажите, в каком формате вы получаете данные из API. JSON?

Comment: @SimonOsipov на скрине уже конечный вывод программы (насколько я понимаю, это обычный текстовый вариант - это тело ответа я сохраняю как csv и использую). Но запрос к API в формате JSON