# Анализ данных с помощью DataFrame Python, полученных через API Яндекс Директ

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Появилась необходимость анализировать огромный массив данных через апи.
Запрос на сервер я прописал, ответ записываю в csv, а уже потом читаю его как DataFrame.
При использовании данного метода у меня получается DataFrame, в котором никак не получается изменить типы данных.

Вопрос: 
1. Стоит ли вообще сохранять ответы сервера в файл, чтобы работать над ним, либо сразу его форматировать в DataFrame?
2. Что нужно сделать с ответом сервера, чтобы в итоге из него получился человеческий DataFrame

Полученный отчет с сервера выводится этой строкой:

> print("Содержание отчета: \n{}".format(u(req.text)))

Тело запроса следующее:

```
    import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from time import sleep
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
# Метод для корректной обработки строк в кодировке UTF-8 как в Python 3, так и в Python 2
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    def u(x):
        try:
            return x.encode("utf8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return x
else:
    def u(x):
        if type(x) == type(b''):
            return x.decode('utf8')
        else:
            return x

# --- Входные данные ---
# Адрес сервиса Reports для отправки JSON-запросов (регистрозависимый)
ReportsURL = 'https://api.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/reports'

# OAuth-токен пользователя, от имени которого будут выполняться запросы
token = 'TOKEN'

# Логин клиента рекламного агентства
# Обязательный параметр, если запросы выполняются от имени рекламного агентства
clientLogin = 'LOGIN'

# --- Подготовка запроса ---
# Создание HTTP-заголовков запроса
headers = {
           # OAuth-токен. Использование слова Bearer обязательно
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
           # Логин клиента рекламного агентства
           "Client-Login": clientLogin,
           # Язык ответных сообщений
           "Accept-Language": "ru",
           # Режим формирования отчета
           "processingMode": "auto"
           # Формат денежных значений в отчете
           # "returnMoneyInMicros": "false",
           # Не выводить в отчете строку с названием отчета и диапазоном дат
           # "skipReportHeader": "true",
           # Не выводить в отчете строку с названиями полей
           # "skipColumnHeader": "true",
           # Не выводить в отчете строку с количеством строк статистики
           # "skipReportSummary": "true"
           }

# Создание тела запроса
body = {
    "params": {
        "SelectionCriteria": {
            "DateFrom": "2018-12-01",
            "DateTo": "2018-12-03"
        },
        "FieldNames": [
            "Date",
            "Impressions",
            "Clicks",
            "Ctr",
            "Cost",
            "AvgCpc",
            "AvgImpressionPosition",
            "AvgClickPosition",
            "AvgTrafficVolume",
            "BounceRate",
            "AvgPageviews",
            "ConversionRate",
            "CostPerConversion",
            "Conversions"
        ],
        "ReportName": u("Report4"),
        "ReportType": "ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
        "DateRangeType": "CUSTOM_DATE",
        "Format": "TSV",
        "IncludeVAT": "NO",
        "IncludeDiscount": "NO"
    }
}


# Кодирование тела запроса в JSON
body = json.dumps(body, indent=4)

# --- Запуск цикла для выполнения запросов ---
# Если получен HTTP-код 200, то выводится содержание отчета
# Если получен HTTP-код 201 или 202, выполняются повторные запросы
while True:
    try:
        req = requests.post(ReportsURL, body, headers=headers)
        req.encoding = 'utf-8'  # Принудительная обработка ответа в кодировке UTF-8
        if req.status_code == 400:
            print("Параметры запроса указаны неверно или достигнут лимит отчетов в очереди")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(u(body)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 200:
            print("Отчет создан успешно")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("Содержание отчета: \n{}".format(u(req.text)))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 201:
            print("Отчет успешно поставлен в очередь в режиме офлайн")
            retryIn = int(req.headers.get("retryIn", 60))
            print("Повторная отправка запроса через {} секунд".format(retryIn))
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            sleep(retryIn)
        elif req.status_code == 202:
            print("Отчет формируется в режиме офлайн")
            retryIn = int(req.headers.get("retryIn", 60))
            print("Повторная отправка запроса через {} секунд".format(retryIn))
            print("RequestId:  {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            sleep(retryIn)
        elif req.status_code == 500:
            print("При формировании отчета произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте повторить запрос позднее")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 502:
            print("Время формирования отчета превысило серверное ограничение.")
            print("Пожалуйста, попробуйте изменить параметры запроса - уменьшить период и количество запрашиваемых данных.")
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(body))
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        else:
            print("Произошла непредвиденная ошибка")
            print("RequestId:  {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(body))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break

    # Обработка ошибки, если не удалось соединиться с сервером API Директа
    except ConnectionError:
        # В данном случае мы рекомендуем повторить запрос позднее
        print("Произошла ошибка соединения с сервером API")
        # Принудительный выход из цикла
        break

    # Если возникла какая-либо другая ошибка
    except:
        # В данном случае мы рекомендуем проанализировать действия приложения
        print("Произошла непредвиденная ошибка")
        # Принудительный выход из цикла
        break
```

Comment: Наверное сервер отвечает в формате JSON, так что можете попробовать метод Pandas  [read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html), метод может принимать URL в качестве аргумента и Pandas сам сделает запрос и распарсит ответ.

Comment: [Повторюсь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924941/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-csv-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-pandas#comment1528025_924941): [приведите пожалуйста в вопросе воспроизводимый пример входных данных (или ссылку на данные) и то что вы хотите получить на выходе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)